# ggplot2: geom_bar stacked barplot, specify bar outline color

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to figure out how to specify the outline color on a stacked barplot in ggplot2. In the below code I specify `color="green"`, which gives a green outline to each of the bars. I would like to specify a different outline color for each bar (e.g. `cut=Fair` would be filled with yellow and outlined with orange, `cut=Good` would be filled with light green and outlined with dark green, etc.).

```
ggplot(diamonds) +  
  geom_bar(aes(clarity, fill=cut))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Fair"="yellow","Good"="light green","Very Good"="light blue","Premium"="pink","Ideal"="purple"))+
```

I have tried `scale_color_manual()` and specifying a vector of colors in the `geom_bar()` aesthetics, neither have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must map both aesthetics to the `cut` variable, and then you can use `scale_colour_manual`. Here is an (ugly) example:

```
ggplot(diamonds) +  
  geom_bar(aes(clarity, fill=cut, colour=cut)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Fair"="brown",
                             "Good"="blue",
                             "Very Good"="green",
                             "Premium"="red",
                             "Ideal"="yellow")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Fair"="yellow",
                             "Good"="light green",
                             "Very Good"="light blue",
                             "Premium"="pink",
                             "Ideal"="purple"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it was something simple like that. That got me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If you like the answer, you can click the check box to the left of the question.