# Change color of outline in multicolored grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a barplot I have:

[image]

How can I have a black outline for each bar and also, change the font size of the axis label and values on the label?

```
mm1=melt(data[,c('label','cut_scorer1','cut_scorer2')], id = 1)
assign(cut_score,ggplot(mm1, aes(x = label, y = value, width = 0.8)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+ sale_fill_manual(values=alpha(c('light green','dark green'),0.7), name = "Scorer", 
    labels = c("1", "2")) + 
    labs(title = paste(subject_name,"Cutting", sep = " - "), x = "", y = 
    "Score") + 
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) + coord_cartesian( ylim = 
    c(min(mm1$value),max(mm1$value))))
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2: geom\_bar stacked barplot, specify bar outline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267417/ggplot2-geom-bar-stacked-barplot-specify-bar-outline-color)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of the above question, as that one is specifically for stacked barplots, which requires an alternative approach using `cut()`.

Comment: cut() does not work for group plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend taking a look at the documentation for `geom_bar()` (as well as the basic `ggplot2` documentation), but this might help get you started.

You can add an outline to your bars by using `colour = "black"`, and you can change the axis labels by using `labs()`. We use the arguments within `theme()` to change the font size on your axis labels and tickmarks. See the code below:

```
# example dataframe
df <- data.frame(time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
                 total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23))

plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = total_bill, fill = time)) +
        geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity") +
        labs(x = "Meal", y = "Total Bill") +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
              axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))
print(plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks.

I added colour = "black" inside geom_bar but outside aes

mm1 = melt(data[,c('label','cut_scorer1','cut_scorer2')], id = 1)
assign(cut_score,ggplot(mm1, aes(x = label, y = value, width = 0.8)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", **colour = "black",** position = "dodge") + 
   scale_color_manual(values = 'black') + 
   scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(c('light green','dark green'),0.7), name = "Scorer", labels = c("1", "2")) + 
   labs(title = paste(subject_name,"Cutting", sep = " - "), x = "", y = "Score") + 
   theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) + coord_cartesian( ylim = c(min(mm1$value),max(mm1$value))))